# EMoji Unicode for IOS

Tags: ios, unicode, emoji

I call api and get the string which include the android java unicode in NSDictionary :

\ud83d\ude25\ud83d\ude1e\U2764\ud83d\ude2d

When get the the value above and assign to string, I just will get the string as:
\ud83d\ude25\ud83d\ude1e❤\ud83d\ude2d

I totally can not get the value \U2764 but get the value ❤
So I can not replace the code \U2764 to IOS unicode.

How can I get it \U2764? I convert into UTF-8.

Thanks

Edit:

This is get the directory from api (dic):

{

```
message = "\ud83d\ude25\ud83d\ude1e\U2764\ud83d\ude2d";
mesgid = "213133";
Thumbnail = "";
```

}

Then i get the message, but the dic2 string is still get  \ud83d\ude25\ud83d\ude1e❤\ud83d\ude2d:

```
const char *cString = [[dic6 objectForKey:@"Message"] UTF8String];

NSString *dic2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:cString];


if ([dic2 rangeOfString:@"\\U"].location==NSNotFound && [dic2 rangeOfString:@"\\u"].location==NSNotFound)
{
    NSLog(@"Substring Not Found");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Substring Found");
}
```

I totally can not get the unicode.
Why?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 NSString *uniString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:@"\ud83d\ude25\ud83d\ude1e❤\ud83d\ude2d
```

"];

Comment: can you paste the exact string here

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will resolve your problem

```
   char cString[] = "\ud83d\ude25\ud83d\ude1e\U2764\ud83d\ude2d";
   NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cString length:strlen(cString)];
   NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: sorry, i had try this. still can not get it.